# Is the memory space of a .NET process secure when compiled in release mode?

Tags: .net, security, clr

Is the memory space of a .NET process secure when the binary was compiled in release mode?

Let's say I generate some random string and it is long lived (not GC'd).

Could someone with access to the OS and the process dump the process's memory and retrieve my randomly generated string - could they perhaps still connect the debugger, interrupt execution and dump some data I would rather not leak out?

Assuming the above is true, is there a compilation flag one can use to safeguard against what I've described?

Comment: "someone with access" is the security problem.  "Being on the other side of the airtight hatchway" as Raymond Chen calls it.  Not only limited to being able to start a process and attach a debugger, the disk drive can be a security problem as well.  The paging file may have a copy of the string, a screwdriver provides access.  Low odds, not zero.  There is no substitute for physical security, a door with a lock.  Systems tend to be secure when the cost of an attack greatly outstrips the benefits of the attack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your strings are retrievable and no there is no magic switch. What's the use case?

Comment: Answers should not contain further questions. That is what comments are for :)